# Start app in the foreground again after closing through the notification "high comsuption energy" on huawei phones

Tags: java, android, service, foreground, huawei-mobile-services

My app when it is a time in foreground execution on mobiles Huawei shows a notification of high power consumption, that after pressing it, the app is closed, how can I prevent it from closing? or how can I start it again?

I have seen that it does not pass through the onDestroy method or onTaskRemove.

Comment: I'd say that it is not up to you to do that. If the user wants to close your app (even through notification by OS), then he should be able to do that.

Comment: The important thing is to be able to detect that behavior, and to be able to act

Comment: Probably you should not be able to act if the user wants your app to stop acting (to be closed immediately)

Comment: It is essential for the operation of my app, to be able to detect it, it is based on a basic service for its correct operation.

Comment: Well, that does not mean that Google or Huawei have to support this feature for you. And it looks like they don't.